# Вопросы к тексту ЕГЭ

Tags: егэ

2)  В предложениях 6-15 содержатся примеры, поясняющие утверждение, сформулиро­ванное в предложении 5.

4)  Предложения 33 и 34 противопоставлены по содержанию.

(5)Никто не объяснял Костяшкину смысл жизни так коротко и просто, как новый при­ятель. (6)По словам Шустикова, все умные люди были ловчилы. (7)Например, его дядя, зубной техник, обжуливал клиентов так, что комар носу не подточит. (8)На каждой золотой коронке он наживал полграмма, а то и грамм золота. (9)У него была дача, обставленная мебелью красного дерева, и каждый год он ездил в Сочи. (10)Дядя был восхитительный ловчила. (11)Учителя, говорил Шустиков, также ловчилы. (12)Они только стараются «зашибить деньгу». (13)На ос­тальное им наплевать. (14)По крайней мере, умным. (15)Сам Шустиков собирался «халтурить и не попадаться» и приманивал Костяшкина такой же будущностью.

«(33)Сын у неё не был шкурой. (34)Сын был орёл.

Здравствуйте! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему один вариант правильный, а другой нет.

Так рассуждал: После 5-го предложения идут примеры, описывающие чем занимаются его родственники, но ведь там нет глаголов, которые отвечали бы на вопрос в чем смысл жизни, по мнению Костяшкина. ( Зашибить деньгу, обманывать всех и т.д.)

33-34 А здесь разве шкура и орёл не противопоставление?

Спасибо!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
  33-34 А здесь разве шкура и орёл не противопоставление?
```

«(33)Сын у неё не был шкурой. (34)Сын был орёл.-Слова противопоставлены, а предложения нет, оба утверждают, что сын - положительный человек.

```
 После 5-го предложения идут примеры, описывающие чем занимаются 
  его  родственники, но ведь там нет глаголов, которые отвечали 
  бы на            вопрос ,           в чем          смысл жизни, по мнению Костяшкина.
```

А в задании речь не о глаголах, а о примерах, каких людей он считал умными. И такие примеры есть. 2 вариант ответа правильный,4-нет